# Mounting data from database with ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to mount data from my database with a componentDidMount. The problem is that it's not giving any response and showing the catch error in the console. I think my url might be incorrect? Anyone that could have a look?

url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/challengedetail/:id`

The error in the console: GET http://localhost:3000/challengedetail/:id 404 (Not Found)

---

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import './Challengedetail.css'
import Responsechallenge from '../components/Responsechallenge'
import axios from "axios"
import TakeChallenge from "../components/Takechallenge"

class Challengedetail extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            title:"",
            description:"",
            responses: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        // debugger
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/challengedetail/:id`,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({
                title: response.data.title,
                description: response.data.description
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Charles this is an ffffffffffferror: ", error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <div className="challengedetailpage">
                    <div className="headercontainer">
                        <div className="challengesectionbox">
                            <h1>{this.state.title}charles</h1>
                            <p>{this.state.description}ffff</p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="takechallengebox">
                            <TakeChallenge/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="responsechallenges">
                        <Responsechallenge/>
                        <Responsechallenge/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default Challengedetail
```

Answer (score 0):

You did use the "get" method with axios. Do this;

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get({
        method: "GET",
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/challengedetail/:id`,
        withCredentials: true
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.setState({
            title: response.data.title,
            description: response.data.description
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Charles this is an ffffffffffferror: ", error)
    })
}
```

Comment: No man that doesn't change anything. the method is set to GET already, so it works the same way

Comment: anyone else could have a look please?